# Afraid of Decision Making Responsibility / Position

Tags: new-job, work-experience, company

I currently work as an analyst in a big company, as many of you, I want some rise in my job position (supervisor, boss, etc). However, as an analyst sometimes I feel the pressure and fear about making some really terrible mistake (I know when something can be a terrible mistake and a small mistake). My boss always helps me, but what scares me is that, if I want a rise in my job possition, that means that hard decisions will be done by myself and the superiors may not tolerate an afraid attitude because of my future boss position.

Has any of you some afraids of making terrible mistakes? Any tips when making hard decisions as a high job position?

Comment: It will be difficult to quantify an answer for you, as the question is very general. If you had a specific example of a "terrible mistake" that you made and asked for suggestions on how to handle it, that would be better. Or if you have a specific "hard decision" and asked for suggestions on how to decide (or how to decide how to decide!) that would be good also.

Comment: I believe there was a similar question on Academia S. Exchange in the past few days. You might want to have a look there.

Answer (score 2):

> that means that hard decisions will be done by myself and the superiors may not tolerate an afraid attitude because of my future boss position.

What do you believe that the increased salary and resources are for?

One of the reasons the positions pays more is because you do carry this burden. While there are things you can do like learning more about your field and always taking time to analyze your risks, you will need to get over your fear of this to advance.

Answer (score 0):

## **Quality Gates and Decision Papers**

I have often faced this dilemma, where I had to take decisions and I am scared if I am doing a mistake. In cases like this, I have often felt that [**quality gating**](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-use-quality-gates-to-guide-it-projects/) has helped me. While the concept comes from software engineering, you can basically use it in any job - and is especially suited for your job. Also, realize it is different from [**passing the buck**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_passing).

If you can in your higher role, hire people who are extremely talented in their field and add them to your team as consultant. If not, use your existing team and boss and set-up a formal approval process for decisions that have high impact (both positive and negative). Even a simple approval flow like below works wonders if implemented properly:

1. Decision by you (make sure to note why and how you arrived at this decision - see decision paper below) - up for team and subject matter expert panel criticism and vote (approve / disapprove) - use tools for comments etc.
2. Approval flow to line manager following the previous step
3. Final approval from top-management

Create this process - use a simple [**Decision Paper**](https://digital.library.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metadc682839/) template and record everything. Also realize, that even the best thought decisions can fail (even coming from best experts). Make sure you have the documentation to prove that at that point of time, the decision was the best one.

Best of luck!

Comment: Explain the downvote please?

Answer (score 0):

Fear of change is an absolutely natural and healthy response. Sometimes fear is reasonable, sometimes, not so much.

In your case (just some examples):

- fear is reasonable if you know that you cannot do the job, and the chance of failure is high.

Solution: before taking the new position, make sure that you learn how to do the job. Talk to your boss about it.

- fear is not so reasonable: you know that you can do the job, but you do not have the experience.

Solution: talk to your boss about it. Whenever you do something (important), have it reviewed by somebody else (maybe even by more people - it depends on the situation), write a short report about the review contents and the decisions taken (and share the report with all the participants immediately after the meeting).

In this way, you share the responsibility with others in an official way - the way it should actually be.

---

> Has any of you some afraids of making terrible mistakes?

As I said, fear is natural and good - when done reasonably. And there is no human being, alive and working, to never do any mistakes. One just needs to prepare, to minimize the number of mistakes, and their magnitude.

> Any tips when making hard decisions as a high job position?

Decisions are decisions. You analyze the data, see what works best. If nothing works, try to find another alternate solution which works.